# What is a command-line macro that controls a run-time check (in C++)?

Tags: c++, runtime, contract

Bjarne Stroustrup wrote in his book *A Tour of C++* (Section 3.5.4) that,

> There is currently no general and standard way of writing optional run-time tests of invariants... For now, we have to rely on ad hoc mechanisms. For example, we could use a command-line macro to control a run-time check:
>
> ```
> double& Vector::operator[](int i)
> {
>     if (RANGE_CHECK && (i<0 || size()<=i))
>         throw out_of_range{"Vector::operator[]"};
>     return elem[i];
> }
> ```

What is he referring to by command-line macro? What is the `RANGE_CHECK` in the code?

Comment: He's referring to passing something like `-DRANGE_CHANGE=1` to the compiler.  Refer to your compiler's documentation for exact syntax.

Comment: Something like `-DRANGE_CHECK=true` on the command line, which is equivalent to putting `#define RANGE_CHECK true` into the source file. If `RANGE_CHECK` expands to something that evaluates to true in boolean context, then the check after it is performed and the exception may be thrown. If it expands to false, then the check is skipped, under the usual rules of `&&` operator.